# Specify Virtual Size using DRM with Frambuffer Emulation

Tags: embedded, framebuffer, drm

I am attempting make use of double buffering on an AM335x processor. We have an example running on a demo image that was not created by us. I am working on putting together our own image using mainline sources.

This system is using the tilcdc driver. We are using the fbdev emulation provided by that driver. As we are setting up the parameters, this call errors out:

```
unsigned int Yold = variable_info.yres_virtual;
variable_info.yres_virtual = variable_info.yres * 2;

if (ioctl(fdfb, FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO, &variable_info))
```

We echoed 0xf into /sys/module/drm/parameters/debug to turn on the elevated debugging printouts for the drm driver. We were able to see the following error message:

fb userspace requested width/height/bpp is greater than current 1024x768-32 (virtual 1024x1536) > 1024x768-32

I have seen references indicating that drm defaults to only allocating enough memory for the attached resolution. I am struggling to find out where that is occurring and how I might increase the amount of memory allocated.

As for the sample image, this was provided to us for testing purposes. We have found that the reason the application works on this image is that the memory being allocated by default is the right size for doing triple buffering at a y height of 768.

Thank you for your help.

*edit additions

I have been looking at the source for the driver and have yet to conclude can be done to change the buffer size upon driver load. I would like to avoid hard coding the value at all costs.

I know that underneath the framebuffer emulation provided directly by the tilcdc there are are calls to create a contiguous memory allocation using the information for the crtcs, but it appears to only be using something called fb->height and width.